# Android Studio Arctic Fox Configure External Documentation

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, editor, android-shortcut

How can I configure code navigation to external documentation help (F1) in Android studio project? Currently, clicking F1 in Kotlin source file is pointing to 'https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/using-code-editor.html' instead of https://developer.android.com/.
Please advise.